# How to show success message and refresh the page together

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have JSP Servlet code which uses AJAX to process user data. In the `success` function of AJAX I want to show a success message to the user and I also want to clear all the fields in the form, so I reload the page. However when I reload the alert disappears. What is the solution for this?

```js
$.ajax({
  url: '../Groups',
  data: {
    "mode": "create_assign",
    "name": name,
    "desc": desc,
    "status": status,
    "add": listadd
  },
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(response) {
    $.notify({
      message: "Created group successfully.",
    }, {
      type: "success"
    });
    location.reload();
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, message) {
    $.notify({
      message: "System Error: Please try again or contact system admin.",
    }, {
      type: "danger"
    });
  },
  complete: function() {
    $('.overlay').hide();
  }
});
```

Comment: You don't really need to reload the page to clear the input fields, you can easily empty them using Jquery. This should solve your problem of the disappearing message.

Comment: Or Use `setTimeout()` Function . After showing message some time may be 1/2/5 second you can reload your page.

Comment: If you really want to reload your page (as mentioned by Chris not really needed) then you need to pass that message to the new reloaded page (for example using local storage)

Answer (score 1):

Reloading the page after making an AJAX request is rather redundant. It makes the entire point of the AJAX request moot.

If all you want to do is clear the fields in the form after submission you could either do it manually:

```
success: function(response) {
  $.notify("Created group successfully.", "success");
  $('#yourForm input').val('');
},
```

Alternatively, you could just reset the `form` to its initial state:

```
success: function(response) {
  $.notify("Created group successfully.", "success");
  $('#yourForm').trigger('reset');
},
```

Note the above examples use the less verbose shorthand call to `$.notify()`, as can be seen in the [documentation](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Its redundant, as mentioned by Chris, but have you considered using setTimeout()?

You could do this for example:

```
function successFunction(response) {
  $.notify({ message: "Created group successfully." }, { type: "success" });
  setTimeout(location.reload(), 4000); // time in milliseconds
}
```

and in your main ajax call add :

```
success: successFunction(response)
```

Comment: This is not very user friendly. Imagine being on a site an all of a sudden the page completely resets.

Comment: It was just an example. I just wanted to show how setTimeout could work. I agree that its not something you could actually use.

Answer (score 0):

Or instead of reloading the page, you could display the success message and then get the form inputs and clear them, which would look like something like this:

```
$('#yourForm').each(function(){
    this.reset();
});
```